# how to get aws account number /id based on EC2 instance which is hosted in amazons

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

how to get aws account number /id based on EC2 instance ip which is hosted in amazon
i have a instance name CTI server it is hosted in one AWS account.
I have the details of CTI server like private ip and hosts and able to do ssh this instance through putty .I want the AWS account number /aws account ID
of where this instance is created .
is their any command to find out account number without login into aws console

Comment: ok thanks,
what are the ways to find the aws account number without console login

Comment: @bryan60 actually yeah there is, see answer below. It's in the EC2 metadata.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can obtain the account number from within an EC2 instance by querying the instance metadata. The metadata is located in http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document.

If an IAM role is attached to the instance, you can retrieve it using:

```
aws sts get-caller-identity
```

Comment: And if you have `jq` installed, you can run `curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .accountId`

Comment: `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document` and pulling out `accountId` is the best approach here since it doesn't require an IAM role be assigned to the instance, or the AWS CLI tool to be installed.

Comment: This gives me "Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure"."

Comment: @parsley72 - you need to attach an IAM role to your EC2 instance for the AWS command to work. Or, you would need to set the access and secret keys.

Comment: The curl command looks at the instance metadata. The AWS command queries AWS API to retrieve the data. These are different commands.

Comment: But don't they give the same result?

Comment: No, they don't provide the same results.

Comment: If you want to avoid grep/sed/jq you can also just ask the awscli to do the parsing: `aws sts get-caller-identity --query "Account" --output text`

Answer (score 10):

This information is available in the dynamic [Instance Metadata](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-metadata.html). It can be extracted in a number of different ways.

### jq

The `jq` JSON parser is the best method currently available, and it comes pre-installed on the AWS Linux AMIs.

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | jq -r .accountId
```

Most other methods I found online tended to make a long chain of process calls like `grep | sed | awk` etc. which is less than ideal. So I explored some alternatives trying to limit the parsing to just one extra process.

### sed

The best alternative I could come up with, using only a single pipe, was with `sed` and extended regular expressions. Plus, unlike the other solutions, this can even handle the (contrived) scenario of (escaped) double quotes in the middle of an accountId:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | sed -nE 's/.*"accountId"\s*:\s*"(.*)".*/\1/p'
```

Or, slightly less readable with plain BRE:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | sed -n 's/.*"accountId"\s*:\s*"\(.*\)".*/\1/p'
```

### grep

`grep` is an option, but requires GNU grep with PCRE support:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep -oP '"accountId"\s*:\s*"\K[^"]+'
```

### grep | cut

This more portable alternative requires an extra step (if avoiding heavier tools like `awk`), but is also more straightforward and easier to understand:

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | grep '"region"' | cut -d\" -f4
```

The `grep` output looks like this:

```
  "region" : "us-east-1"
```

Then `cut` will split on double quotes and pick the fourth field.

### awk

I try to avoid using awk for simple uses like this, but it can obviously do the above in one step. It may sometimes be the only available option (e.g busybox):

```
curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | awk -F'"' '/"accountId"/ { print $4 }'
```

Comment: `jq` is not preinstalled on AWS Linux 2 AMI.

Comment: Yes, AWS Linux 2 is an LTS distribution, so it has a very limited set of core packages because Amazon is promising long-term user-space ABI compatibility. Other packages have been moved to the _extras_ channel. In the other AWS Linux AMI, jq has been available since [version 2013.03](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2013.03-packages/#j)

Answer (score 3):

Without jq you can use this one.

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document|grep accountId| awk '{print $3}'|sed  's/"//g'|sed 's/,//g'
```

Comment: FWIW, can strip both " and , in one pass with  | grep accountId | awk '{print $3;}' | sed 's/[",]//g'
But since this is all hacky anyway, this works too..  Let awk do the search (don't need grep) and change awk's separator char to " and fetch the 4th item.  
curl --silent http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | awk -F\" '/accountId/{print $4;}'

Answer (score 1):

The following will give you AWS Account ID:

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/network/interfaces/macs/02:a2:1f:d5:fe:0f/owner-id
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution with use of metadata without jq

`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | sed '2q;d' |cut -d : -f2 | awk -F\" '{print $2}'`

Comment: `accountId` is not guaranteed to be on the 2nd line or on any particular line.