# How to get AWS account ID from curl in powershell

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell

Does anyone know how to get the AWS account id in Powershell? I would like to do the this from the curl command, and have this running well under Linux from here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597492/how-to-get-aws-account-number-id-based-on-ec2-instance-which-is-hosted-in-amazo#:~:text=You%20can%20obtain%20the%20account,%2Finstance%2Didentity%2Fdocument.&text=This%20gives%20me%20%22Unable%20to,running%20%22aws%20configure%22.%22](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51597492/how-to-get-aws-account-number-id-based-on-ec2-instance-which-is-hosted-in-amazo#:%7E:text=You%20can%20obtain%20the%20account,%2Finstance%2Didentity%2Fdocument.&text=This%20gives%20me%20%22Unable%20to,running%20%22aws%20configure%22.%22)

Specifically this:

`curl -s http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document | sed -nE 's/.*"accountId"\s*:\s*"(.*)".*/\1/p'`

And I can use the curl command in windows get get the same output but without parsing like this

`curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document`

but I have no idea how to parse and get just the accountId number, or the instanceId if I need that.

I have tried the Select statement, but get no meaningful results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the account ID, you can use:

```
$account_id = ((curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document).Content | ConvertFrom-Json).accountId
```

For the instance ID, you can use:

```
$instance_id = (curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id).Content
```

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me (based on Paolo's answer, while his code 'as is' didn't work):

```
$accountId = ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("http://169.254.169.254/latest/dynamic/instance-identity/document") | ConvertFrom-Json).accountId
```